# Can we use boolean operator in Delphi XE2 LiveBinding expression?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, livebindings

I am planning to write a Live Binding source expression for TCheckBox:

```
SourceExpression = '(Checked = False) and (Enabled = True)'
```

When execute the code, an exception prompted:

```
Expected EOF - trailing text in expression
```

Is Delphi XE2 Live Binding support boolean operator?

Comment: Just a wild guess - have you tried to use `SourceExpression = '(not Checked) and (Enabled)'` ? And why ? Because it hurts my eyes whenever I see `=` in boolean expression :-) But don't have Delphi XE2 right now...

Comment: `not Checked` is not supported, so I use `Checked = False`

Comment: Look at this SO question: [How to write live binding expression that control TEdit.PasswordChar based on TCheckBox.Checked?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11573434/576719). The accepted answer registers a boolean expression evaluator.

Comment: AFAIK you can't use the logical operators (`and`, `or`, ´not´ , ´xor´, ´shl´, ´shr´) in a LiveBinding expression :(, as workaround you can register a custom method to evaluate the logical operation.

Comment: shl and shr are not logical operators. It's impossible to believe that live bindings don't support logical operators.

Comment: Impossible to believe, and yet sadly, apparently, true!

Answer (score 1):

No, boolean operators are not supported directly.

From the [docu](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Using_Custom_Format_and_Parse_Expressions_in_LiveBindings):

> You can use the following math symbols in your expressions:
>
> - Constants: nil True False Pi
> - Arithmetic operators: + - * /
> - Logic operators: = <> < <= > >=
> - Parentheses, (), to change operator precedence.

But you can use [the builtin functions `IfAll()`, `IfAny()` and `IfThen()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Default_LiveBindings_Methods) instead of `and`, `or` and `not`:

```
SourceExpression := 'IfAll(IfThen(Checked, False, True), Enabled)'
```

Or you [register your own functions](http://www.malcolmgroves.com/blog/?p=1226).

I tested this 4 XE4, but it should work for XE2 2.

- `A or B`: `IfAny(A, B)`
- `A and B`: `IfAll(A, B)`
- `not A`: `IfThen(A, False, True)`
- `A xor B`: `IfAll(IfAny(A, B), IfThen(IfAll(A,B), False, True))`